# order by doesn`t work in partition by clause in POSTGRESQL?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I have a postgresql table like this:
[image]

I want to count the continous dt value with the cap = 0.0000 group by id,and I tried this:

```
select id ,dt,cap ,row_number() OVER ( partition by id,cap order by id,dt) t1 from tbl
```

I supposed to get the result like this:

| id | dt | cap | t1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10470 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00 | 0.0000 | 1 |
| 10470 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 0.0000 | 2 |
| 10470 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 0.0000 | 3 |
| 10470 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 200.0000 | 1 |
| 10470 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00 | 0.0000 | 1 |
| 10470 | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | 0.0000 | 2 |
| 10470 | 2021-06-01 00:00:00 | 0.0000 | 3 |

but acctually its result is like bellow:

| id | dt | cap | t1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10470 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00 | 0.0000 | 1 |
| 10470 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 0.0000 | 2 |
| 10470 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 0.0000 | 3 |
| 10470 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00 | 0.0000 | 4 |
| 10470 | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | 0.0000 | 5 |
| 10470 | 2021-06-01 00:00:00 | 0.0000 | 6 |
| 10470 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 200.0000 | 1 |

How to get the result I wanted ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  The logic you want is that a row number sequence should always start again at 1 whenever we encounter a non zero `cap` value within a given `id` block of records, as ordered by the `dt` column.

One way to approach this uses the difference in row numbers method:

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id,
                                 CASE WHEN cap < 0.0001 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                                 ORDER BY dt) rn2
    FROM tbl
)

SELECT id, dt, cap,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, rn2-rn1 ORDER BY dt) AS t1
FROM cte1
ORDER BY id, dt;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

One comment here is that I am using the following `CASE` expression to detect a zero or non zero in the `cap` column:

```sql
CASE WHEN cap < 0.0001 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Note that I define "zero" as just being less than `0.0001`.  The reason for this is floating point values are not exact in Postgres.  Therefore, the following `CASE` expression might not behave as expected, due to a "zero" `cap` value not really be exactly zero:

```sql
CASE WHEN cap = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```